# When an effect is applied to wpf progress bar the output get slow down

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, storyboard

I have created a audio equalizer using wpf progressive bars. By changing the values of different progressive bars the equalizer effect is created.It worked fine.
But after adding a effect to the progressive bars, the animation is being slow down.
This is the blur effect I added.

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                        <Setter Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <BlurEffect Radius="6" KernelType="Gaussian"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </StackPanel.Resources>
```

What would be the reason for that slowing down and how to overcome it.. ?

Comment: Adding effects to progress bars will cause more rendering to take place, therefore it's expected that performance will take a hit. Perhaps you can consider creating your own Progress Bar control? Or override the template.

Comment: From the docs - "WPF bitmap effects are rendered in software mode. Any object that applies an effect will also be rendered in software. Performance is degraded the most when using Bitmap effects on large visuals or animating properties of a Bitmap effect." --- and from my personal experience, a Blur effect on something animated is a killer on performance and will crash the app on lesser powered machines.